# BufferedWriter not writing ALL the information

Tags: java, printwriter, bufferedwriter, writer

I am making a simple tutorial program in which the user inputs some data, then that data is written into a textfile, then the textfile is read and the data displayed. However, not all of the data is being written into the textfile. Please view the following:

This is my code:

```
package chasi.fecalMatter.ExcrementalProgram;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RedundantExcrement {

    static String inputName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your FULL name:");
    static String inputUsername = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your desired Username:");
    static String inputJobTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your Job title:");
    static String inputSalary = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your monthly salary:");

    static int convertedSalary = 0; /*Convert salary from String to int*/
    static int benefitDeduction = 0;

    static String empFileName = inputUsername+"INFO";
    static BufferedWriter bwriter = null;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Catch NumberFormatException.
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(inputSalary);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please ensure that " +
                    "your salary is entered in NUMERIC form.", "ERROR!", 2);
            return;
        }

        //Specify instructions as regard salary -to- Benefit deduction ratio
        if (convertedSalary >= 3500) {
            benefitDeduction = 300;
        } else {
            benefitDeduction = 180;
        }

    try { /*Catches IOException AND NullPointerException*/ 
            FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(empFileName);
            bwriter = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);

            bwriter.write(inputName);
            bwriter.newLine();
            bwriter.write(inputJobTitle);
            bwriter.newLine();
            bwriter.write(inputSalary);
            bwriter.newLine();
            bwriter.write(benefitDeduction);
            bwriter.newLine();
            bwriter.write("----------");
            bwriter.newLine();              
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ionpEx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An ERROR has occured", "ERROR!", 2);
            return;
        } finally { /*CLOSE the writer*/                
            try{
                if (bwriter != null) {
                    bwriter.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioEx2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR!");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use the int `convertedSalary` to convert the user-inputted `inputSalary` from a String into a number. In my method, I use

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(inputSalary);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please ensure that " +
            "your salary is entered in NUMERIC form.", "ERROR!", 2);
    return;
}
```

In order to covert it. It is later (supposed) to be written by the BufferedWriter.

I also have this code:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(inputSalary);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please ensure that " +
                "your salary is entered in NUMERIC form.", "ERROR!", 2);
    return;
}
```

In order to change the value of my `benefitDeduction` depending on the value of the user's salary.

HOWEVER, the `benefitDeduction` is written into the text file, but instead, I get this: [image: The result of running the program]

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: `I also have this code` is this a copy & paste error? It contains the same code as above.

Comment: Which jdk are you using? There is no `BufferedWriter.write(String)` method in standard java. Does your code actually compile?

Comment: Btw: it seems that `convertedSalary` will always be `0`, because you're not assigning the returned value of `Integer.parseInt(inputSalary);` to it. And there is no variably `userSalary`, but `inputSalary` seems to get written into the file, because it contains `2500` as the third row (that is `bwriter.write(inputSalary);`).

Comment: @Dima Of course there is. It is inherited from [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)

Comment: @Dima jdk7. Yes it does compile

Comment: @Tom oh, silly me! Haha I didn't notice that. But how can I make sure that the benefitDeduction is written?

Comment: @MrChasi Don't write it as int ;). See the Jaggers answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(int)).

```
public void write(int c)
   throws IOException
```

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in
>   the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order
>   bits are ignored.

This means that the int is actually a char and will be converted according to Unicode/ASCII table.

To write the integer value use `bwriter.writer(String.valueOf(benefitDeduction));`

Comment: Which might be why there is a single quote instead of a number written

Comment: @MrChasi It also looks like you would rather use [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) which has `println` methods that would suit you well.

Comment: Okay, that's great, thanks for your help. I'm a java novice, so I wasn't aware of this. Is this the same for all number variables? Including double & long?

Comment: @MrChasi check out the API for that answer :-)

Comment: @MrChasi Look at `PrintWriter` API it would simplify your code a lot.

Comment: Thanks guys! That's a great help. Be sure to upvote this useful question ;)

Answer (score 4):

There are two major problems with your code.

First, you are not actually assigning the value from your `ParseInt` to your `convertedSalary` variable. Hence, it will always be zero.

Then again, you are not writing `convertedSalary` to the file, either.

Second, I think you are confusing between `BufferedWriter.write(int)` and `PrintWriter.print(int)`. The `BufferedWriter` will print the character represented by this integer if it is between `0` and `65535` (or the whatever there is in its lower two bytes if it isn't).

So, if your integer is, for example, 65, what you will have printed is the character `A`, whose value is `65` in Unicode.

So maybe you should be using a `PrintWriter` rather than a `BufferedWriter` there. Or convert the numbers into strings as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the other answers, your problem is the call of `write(int)`. But instead of worrying about the conversion, you can also use `StringBuilder` to create your text first and write it with one call of `write(String)`. That way you don't have to worry about the type of `benefitDeduction`:

```
final String inputName = "Tom";
final String inputJobTitle = "Developer";
final String inputSalary = "1337";
final int benefitDeduction = 180;

try(final BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("blub.txt"))) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(inputName);
    builder.append("\n").append(inputJobTitle);
    builder.append("\n").append(inputSalary);
    builder.append("\n").append(benefitDeduction);
    builder.append("\n----------\n");
    bwriter.write(builder.toString());
} catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An ERROR has occured", "ERROR!", 2);
  return;
}
```

Also note, that I used the [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to handle the `BufferedWriter`. It will handle the resource and closes it for you. No need to do that manually.

The above code write the following data into the file `"blub.txt"`:

```
Tom
Developer
1337
180
----------
```

---

And as I already wrote in the comment, you're not assigning a new value to the variable `convertedSalary`.

Change the line:

```
Integer.parseInt(inputSalary);
```

to:

```
convertedSalary = Integer.parseInt(inputSalary);
```

to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you are writing your numbers, these values are being written as binary numbers not as text numbers. You can fix this by doing `writer.write("" + myNumber);`

Comment: Ok, with "myNumber" being a predefined int of mine?

Comment: @MrChasi yes, depending on what you mean by predefined

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(inputSalary) //returns an integer

Quoting from the JDK:
Integer.parseInt(); = "Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method."

Your code should read:

convertedInt = Integer.parseInt(inputSalary);